# Adjusting Google and Facebooks official Log-In Button with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, facebook-android-sdk, google-authentication, social-authentication

I'm trying to add Google and Facebook Login through the [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to my App. 
When I add the official Google & Facebook Log-In button at a LinearLayout it looks like below:

(Nexus 5X API 25):

[image]

or even worse, like this (LG G7 ThinQ API 28):

[image]

---

***Objective***: 
My Goal is to make them look like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

**Things done so far:** 
 
I am currently using the **official xml code** from [Googles](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) and [Facebooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) Developer-Page

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/google_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

*So I figured out that the following **two aspects** needed to be fixed in order to adjust the two buttons:*

1) **The difference in the length of the two Sign-In Buttons**

- This difference has to do with the fact that Googles Sign-In Button has a small boxshadow. 
   So if you set both Buttons to a fixed width Googles visible Sign-In will always be smaller.

2) **The position of each text**

- Here I tried to adjust the text of the Facebook button but it doesn't seem to work.

---

***EDIT:***

I've decided to inspect the background of the Google Sign-In button. 
 It seems that the background has the following specifications:

[image]

So I adjusted the Facebook Button according to the values above and came up with:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/google_login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="11dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>
```

Now the buttons look like this (without the red lines) [Nexus 5X API25]:

[image]

I Would be perfectly happy but when I look at them with the [Nexus 5X API28] it looks like this:
[image]

How can we fix this? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the width and height of the buttons from your layout as follows.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/google_login_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but in my activity the height of the Facebook-Button doesn't seem to have any effect. Is the mentioned difference of 30dps between the Facebook and Google button randomly picked?

Comment: My suggestion was to set a fixed width and height for the buttons. Sorry for the confusion. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: I see! But because of the shadow of the background from the Google-Login Button I can't figure out the fitting height for each box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it help you.

1) Try to do same `width` of all  Layout and both Buttons `match_parent`OR `0dp`.

2) Remove `android:layout_weight` from Layout if you can.

"Happy Coding"

````
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/google_login_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>```
````

Comment: I tried both but unfortently both variants doesn't fix my problem. Setting the width to `0dp` results in a no-show and setting it to `match_parent` continues with the problem described below. Thank you anyway :)